# webcam using phone

Tags: python, webcam, ubuntu-10.04

am tryin to create an app that should make my cellphone work as a webcam ...
there are softwres like smart cam for that...
also there is an app like mycam that lets you use a gif and create a vistual cam ...
i want to know how an app like that works... 
i want to know which directory to put the temp images for the video .. ???
any clues ?
im using ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

It depends more on the operating system of your phone, not your computer.

For Android, check out [IP Webcam](http://lifehacker.com/#!5650095). For iPhone, check out [iWebcamera](http://www.redmondpie.com/your-iphone-as-webcam-with-iwebcamera-9140802/).

For Symbian, [SmartCam is open source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartcam/files/smartcam_symbian/SmartCamS60_v1_4_1/).

Comment: and isnt there like a temporary location on the pc where the image/video is buffered before sending  ?